# Why Distance Matrix api not more choices?

Tags: google-api, google-distancematrix-api

[image]

[image]

```
origins=22.207741,113.550858
```

And

```
destinations=22.206861,113.538971
```

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=22.207741,113.550858&destinations=22.206861,113.538971&mode=driving&language=zh-TW&key=[YOUR KEY]`

Answer (score 0):

distance matrix api just gives the fastest route result.
you can seperate your route to match the route you are driving.
like multiple origins and destinations.

Consider quota usage as it calculated by elements = (origin count x destionations count) not per request as in directions api.